# bilinear transformation $\phi U\times V\to W$ such that $Im(\phi)=\{\phi(u,v): u\in U, v\in V\}$ is not a subspace of $W$

Tags: linear-algebra, examples-counterexamples, bilinear-form

Find a bilinear transformation $\phi U\times V\to W$ such that $Im(\phi)=\{\phi(u,v): u\in U, v\in V\}$ is not a subspace of $W$

I truly don't have an idea otherwise to brute force lots of tries and find one that fits. Is there a technique of some sort that can help?

Comment: To show that W is a subspace you want to show that $u$+c$v$ $\in$ W for $u,v\in W$ and a scalar c. In this case, we want $\phi(u_1,v_1) + c \phi(u_2,v_2) \in $ W.  Since $\phi$ is bilinear, we would need $c \phi(u_2,v_2)= \phi(cu_2,v_2) = \phi(u_2,cv_2)$. So I guess that would be a place to start. Find a $\phi$ where that isn't true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no technique, but you might want to consider the case $U=V=\Bbb{R}^2$ and the map $\phi$ that sends a pair to the four coordinate products. That is to say
$$\phi:\ \Bbb{R}^2\times\Bbb{R}^2\ \longrightarrow\ \Bbb{R}^4: ((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2))\ \longmapsto\ (x_1x_2,x_1y_2,y_1x_2,y_1y_2).$$